# C# Graphics and Bitmap

Tags: c#

i'm trying to add an image to a C# project and it's always set to NULL and i get this warning 'Snake_Game.Form3.GFX' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null.
Here is what i tried to do.

```
private Graphics GFX;

public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CreateGraphics();
        }
```

And in other function i added this:

```
GFX.DrawImage(Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\C#\Buton.png"), new Point(0, 0));
```

What should I do?

Comment: OMG you have some serious issues here. I suggest you begin by reading a book on OOP and after that another book on C# and .Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your Graphics object before use

```
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GFX = this.CreateGraphics();
    }
```

then when you try to use it to DrawImage it is not null and you can call its methods.
However, let me say that this is the wrong way to go. You keep a Graphics object for the lifetime of your form consuming valuable system resources.
It is a good practice to create the object just before the usage and destroy it immediately after

So remove the initialization in the form constructor and the declaration at the global level

```
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

and, when you need the object call

```
    using(Graphics GFX = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
         GFX.DrawImage(Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\C#\Buton.png"), new Point(0, 0));

         .... // Other graphic code here

    } // This close brace destroy the GFX object releasing its resources.
```

Some useful links for you

[CreateGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
[using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: And another little thing. How to detect the location (I know it but i want to use it because I want to make this buton movable) and the function that verifies if this image is clicked.

Comment: The functions for bitmap images that are equal to the functions of a picturebox mousedown and mouseup.

Comment: Can't help on this. Try posting another question so you will receive more attention from other members.